# ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, authorization

I am currently at the beginning process of starting a new application and am quite new to MVC and Angular. So far i have created a custom authorize attribute using asp.net MVC, this enables me to use the [Authorize] tag. Is it possible to use with an AngularJS front-end?

Any resources that will point me in the right directions would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you see this presentation. I believe it answers your questions very well. https://goo.gl/FXamny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJs is really good for single-page-applicaitons (SPA). So just separate your front-end and back-end layers. Use Angular to implement all the views and front-end stuff. Use ASP.NET WebAPI to expose REST API for front-end (and maybe mobile) app.

---

A few useful links:

[Angular Routing module](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route)

[ASP.NET WebAPI Bearer token authorization with AngularJs](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

[Routing in SPA with AngularJs](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)

Comment: Thanks il take a look now.

Comment: But as I understand Andrei wants to benefit from other great ASP.NET MVC features like authentication and authorization, so your answer is good but does completely answer his question. I'll try to answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES! So you can still benefit from ASP.NET MVC features like authentication and authorization etc. and still use AngularJS on the client.

I actually had the same question and after a bit of research I discovered the following.

It's true we should embrace SPAs (single page apps) but at the same time we should not just discard mature server-side frameworks such ASP.NET MVC. You can simply have a **hybrid web app** or **mini SPA** as we also call them. These web applications use normal ASP.NET MVC routing to show views and then, once the view loads you can leave all the responsabilities to AngularJS. [Miguel Castro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f67PFtrldGQ) uses the term **SPA silos**. Plus you can benefit from AngularJS' routing as well. Miguel Castro also explains how to use them both together to get the best of server and client side. I really suggest seeing his presentation (link below).

In that way you can still benefit from ASP.NET MVC great features like Authentication, Authorization and others but still have AngularJS run your views.

I got this answer on the following locations that you definitely should check out:

- [Miguel Castro: AngularJS for ASP.NET MVC Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f67PFtrldGQ)
- [PluralSight - Cooper, Eames: AngularJS for .NET Developers](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-dotnet-developers)
- [StackOverflow: Mixing Angular and ASP.NET MVC/Web api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097592/mixing-angular-and-asp-net-mvc-web-api)
- [StackOverflow: ASP.NET MVC and Angular JS tipping point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330821/asp-net-mvc-and-angular-js-tipping-point)